# mysql negative lookahead for a group of letters

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a mysql regexp that takes any 3letter combinations except 'BCN', 'LED' and 'ATH'. I've been trying

```
'[^?=BCN|LED|ATH]'
```

(and many many others in vain!) but this also excludes combinations like 'ACE' or 'BCB'. Unfortunately it seems to me that '?!' is not working in mysql. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does it mean you need to only match entries like `ABC`, `XYZ`? You need to use a simple `WHERE col REGEXP '^[A-Z]{3}$'`  regex and add conditions like `WHERE col <> 'BCN'`....

Comment: MySQL's regular expression library is ancient (1994-03-17 was latest release used) and does not support lookahead, nor lookbehind, nor multibyte characters.

Comment: Try `... WHERE col REGEXP '^[A-Z]{3}$' AND col <> 'BCN' AND col <> 'LED' AND col <> 'ATH'`.

Comment: MariaDB's regexp can handle lookarounds; MySQL cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have three forbidden words, you can write the basic version:

```
'[^BLA]..|B([^C].|C[^N])|L([^E].|E[^D])|A([^T].|T[^H])'
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vC2NIqOU4oSS6tsk)

Comment: You made my day! Thanks a lot. The WHERE solution is in my case no option as I can't change it in the application.